# Get input values from conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to generate a shiny app that will first allow the user to (using the notion of dplyr verbs) select the variables they are interested in and then filter those variables based on subsequent selections. I am trying to do this using `conditionalPanel()` but I am getting stuck finding a way to access the `input$` from each conditional panel.

Here is an example:

```
library('shiny')
library('tidyverse')
library('shinyWidgets')

#Create the data
data <- select(mtcars, c(gear, carb))

#Create page with sidebarlayout
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      #Create picker input where relevant variables are selected
      pickerInput(
        inputId = 'vars', 
        label = 'Variables', 
        choices = colnames(data), 
        selected = colnames(data), 
        multiple = T, 
        pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE)
      ),
    
      #Create conditional panels which show when the variable above is selected
      #These panels will be used to filter the data that is selected based on the above variables
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.vars.includes('gear')", 
                     pickerInput(inputId = 'gear', 
                                 label = 'Gear', 
                                 choices = unique(data$gear),
                                 selected = unique(data$gear), 
                                 multiple = T, 
                                 pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE)
                      )
      ), 
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.vars.includes('carb')",
                     pickerInput(inputId = 'carb',
                                 label = 'Carb',
                                 choices = unique(data$carb),
                                 selected = unique(data$carb),
                                 multiple = T,
                                 pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE)
                      )
    )
    ), 
  
  mainPanel(
    #Show the selected data
    verbatimTextOutput('term_selected'), 
    #Show the selected and filtered data - this won't show
    verbatimTextOutput('term_selected_filtered'),
    #Try debug with just getting the 
    verbatimTextOutput('debug_print')
  )
    
  )
)
  
server <- function(input, output) {
  #Create the reactive selected data
  selected_data <- reactive ({
    data %>% 
      select(input$vars)
  })
  
  #Render the selected data
  output$term_selected <- renderPrint(selected_data())
  
  #This is where i am stuck
  #I need to find a way to access the inputs related to the conditional functions
  # selected_filtered_data <- reactive ({
  #   for (i in length(input$vars)) {
  #     selected_data() %>%
  #       filter(input$[first condiitonal panel select] %in% as.symbol(input$vars[i])
  #   }
  # })
  # 
  output$term_selected_filtered <- renderPrint(selected_filtered_data())
  
  #Try to render input input$[first item of input.vars]
  output$debug_print <- renderPrint(input$as.symbol(input$vars[1]))
  
}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The problem lies in the server. I have tried `input$as.symbol(input$vars[1])` to access the `input$gear` (assuming that was selected), but it just throws the error: `attempt to apply non-function`. I tried adding `!!` as syntactic sugar in front of `as.symbol()`, but that makes no difference.

I also tried this, in the hope that i could conditionally filter, and had no luck.

```
  selected_filtered_data <- reactive({
    selected_data() %>%
      if('gear' %in% input$vars) {
        filter(gear %in% input$gear) %>%
      }
      if('carb' %in% input$vars) {
        filter(carb %in% input$carb)
      }
  })
```

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `across` (if we want to `filter` the rows when both column conditions are TRUE) or replace `across` with `if_any` (if either one of them is TRUE when they are both selected)

```
selected_data() %>%
         filter(across(all_of(intersect(input$vars,
        c('gear', "carb"))), ~ .x %in% input[[cur_column()]]))
```

-full code

```
library('shiny')
library('dplyr')
library(tidyr)
library('shinyWidgets')

#Create the data
data <- select(mtcars, c(gear, carb))

#Create page with sidebarlayout
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      #Create picker input where relevant variables are selected
      pickerInput(
        inputId = 'vars', 
        label = 'Variables', 
        choices = colnames(data), 
        selected = colnames(data), 
        multiple = TRUE, 
        pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE)
      ),
      
      #Create conditional panels which show when the variable above is selected
      #These panels will be used to filter the data that is selected based on the above variables
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.vars.includes('gear')", 
                       pickerInput(inputId = 'gear', 
                                   label = 'Gear', 
                                   choices = unique(data$gear),
                                   selected = unique(data$gear), 
                                   multiple = T, 
                                   pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE)
                       )
      ), 
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.vars.includes('carb')",
                       pickerInput(inputId = 'carb',
                                   label = 'Carb',
                                   choices = unique(data$carb),
                                   selected = unique(data$carb),
                                   multiple = TRUE,
                                   pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE)
                       )
      )
    ), 
    
    mainPanel(
      #Show the selected data
      verbatimTextOutput('term_selected'), 
      #Show the selected and filtered data - this won't show
      verbatimTextOutput('term_selected_filtered'),
      #Try debug with just getting the 
      verbatimTextOutput('debug_print')
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  #Create the reactive selected data
  selected_data <- reactive ({
    req(input$vars)
    data %>% 
      select(input$vars)
  })
  
  #Render the selected data
  output$term_selected <- renderPrint(selected_data())
  
  #This is where i am stuck
  #I need to find a way to access the inputs related to the conditional functions
   selected_filtered_data <- reactive ({
     
       
       
       selected_data() %>%
         filter(across(all_of(intersect(input$vars, c('gear', "carb"))), ~ .x %in% input[[cur_column()]]))
     
   })
  # 
  output$term_selected_filtered <- renderPrint(
    
       selected_filtered_data()
       )
  
  output$debug_print <- renderPrint(input[[input$vars[1]]])

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]